# nested set creat sub tree

Tags: php, tree, nested-sets

I have tree created with nested set which looks like:

```
user1
...user2
...user3
......user4
......user5
...user6
user7
...user8
```

DataBase Table schemat:

```
------------------------------------------
|usr_id |usr_name | usr_left | usr_right |
------------------------------------------
```

And i have array with ID of users to get but i have to keep structure of tree if i get any of user and his parent for example

if I want to get user1,user2 and user7 i want result will be:

```
user1
...user2
user7
```

if i want to get user3 and user6 and for example user8 result should be

```
user3
user6
user7
```

because user 7 and user 3 or 6 has not the same parents

but if i want to get tree with user1 and user4 (level 0 and level2) i want to get

```
user1
...[empty_indent-block]
......user4
```

so i have to keep structure with skip users which aren't in array.

I think about get all users from my array and group it by **usr_left** && **usr_right** but i don't know how can I do it in a simple way

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Answer (score 0):

So i have array with users which represents structures of them and array looks like:

```
array { 
    [0] => array{ 
               'id' => ID_OF_USER,
               'name' => NAME_OF_USER,
               'left' => LEFT_INDEX,
               'right'=> RIGHT_INDEX
           } 
    .
    .
    .
 }
```

and i have to create tree of this array so if id of **element** is beetwen left and right of other element - **element2** then element is child of element2

next i have to convert my tree to one dimension array with level of indents

Comment: i have reccurence function to create flat array of tree with setting levels but i need to create this tree first and i don't know how,